# Набить оскомину

Tags: фразеология

В вопросе о "как" я употребила выражение "набить оскомину" и задумалась: а откуда оно вообще взялось?
Оскомина - это, как я понимаю, ощущение неприятного послевкусия (если только это не переносное выражение), но почему ее набивают? И почему так говорят о вещах, которые надоели, которые часто упоминаются?

Answer (score 2):

Единственная параллель, которая пришла на ум  — набить оскомину можно точно так же, как набивают рот едой, т.е. "набить" — взять в рот слишком много. Пища в таком количестве, соответственно, приедается. Поэтому, тот кто ест слишком много (торопливо набивает рот пищей) рискует набить оскомину (т.е. пища ему приестся).

Comment: оскомина,выражение на лице, мина. это когда кислятину ешь,  очень кислым можно и язву на языке или щеке поиметь, типа обжечь слизистую.

Answer (score 1):

Оскомина - ощущение во рту терпкости и вяжущей кислоты. Есть прилагательное "оскоминный". В родственных языках - украинское "оскома", болгарское "скомина", в русских диалектах глагол "оскомить" - вызвать оскомину. **Набить оскомину**, то есть в переносном значении "надоесть", означает *набить рот чем-то поначалу кажущимся вкусным, но из-за слишком большого количества ставшим противным, надоевшим*.

Answer (score 0):

Вот интересное мнение
[Что значит “набить оскомину”?](https://brjunetka.ru/chto-znachit-nabit-oskominu/)

> Такое высказывание может употребляться и в прямом, медицинском значении, ведь именно так называется особенная реакция человеческого организма на кислую еду: лимоны, недозрелые фрукты или ягоды. Такое щемящее чувство может возникнуть из-за частого употребления слив или зелёных яблок.
>
> Проявляется оно в виде снижения чувствительности зубной эмали и возникающей вследствие этого резкой боли, которая проходит практически сразу же, когда устраняется предмет раздражения.
>
> Глагол «набить» в данном варианте означает «натереть, причинив неприятные ощущения». Слово «оскомина», в свою очередь, произошла от устаревшего «скомить», значащего «болеть» или «ныть». По прошествии нескольких лет устойчивое выражение стало использоваться и в переносном смысле, обозначая то, что сильно приелось или надоело. Его можно встретить даже в классической литературе – в своё время фразеологизм в произведениях употребляли Крылов, Чехов, Шолохов и другие.

Действительно, в словаре Кузнецова находим:

> [НАБИТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)....6. что. Ударами, трением намять, натереть что-л. (на теле). Н. мозоли. Н. шишки.